# Microsoft Graph: get user timezone

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

Through a user's delegated permission, we have access to the calendar availabilities of other users (`Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared`). Thanks to this, we can find suitable meeting times for several stakeholders [(user.findMeetingTimes)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-findmeetingtimes?view=graph-rest-1.0) then send out invites from the consenting user's calendar.

However, we can't find timezone information anywhere: we need to know the timezone of other users so that we can properly schedule events based on time constraints.

Currently, we use an application scope `MailboxSettings.Read` that requires admin consent, but we have issues with some groups that decline to give a delegated admin permission. The only alternative I can see is an Oauth2 flow, for each user, to allow us to read this information, but this creates a lot of unnecessary friction for some very basic data.

Is there an alternative that I have missed? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You need `MailboxSettings` but also, I think you're confusing Delegated with Application scopes. Delegated scopes are _only_ applied when you are authenticating a user (the "user delegates authority to your app").

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question